# Confusion in Subscription(In App purchase) of Newsstand App

Tags: objective-c, ios, storekit

I am new to Newsstand App. I have gone through many references of the same. But I have some doubts. Here is my confusions :

1) Consider a user installs a newsstand app on the month October. But the same application have issues on the months from JAN to SEP also. So when the user installs the app, do need to alert     him of the previous issues of the publisher? or just the issue of current month only? Or when the user installs app, do need to list all the issues available with the Publisher and all are locked? or the issues will be listed only if he subscribed for any particular period?

2) Regarding the In App purchase, where should give the purchase section in the app, like in a separate page or along with listed issues. For ex:- When the user install app, it contains many issues listed and do need to give a purchase icon in each cell of the tableview list, if the issue is not purchased? Otherwise do need to show the purchase icon in another view? eg:- 1 Month Subscription or 1 Year Subscription

3) How restoring of issues can be handled? eg:- User may subscribed to 1 month subscription on the months AUG and SEP and the app was deleted from the device. Then again he installed, how this situation can be handled? How the client device will identify whether the user already purchased a few issues in the previous month? Does Store Kit provides any help or do need to handle all the purchase info in the web server or with apple server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1) & 2) are up to you & your personal design choices.

3) Subscriptions use the standard IAP restore StoreKit functions, found in [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW2).